# Weird value coming from TableViewController which is filled with data from JSON

Tags: ios, json, uitableview, nsarray, uistoryboardsegue

Today I encountered bug, that I'm unable to replicate and it is very confusing for me.
Ok little background:

I'm currently working on app, that has tab bar controller as initial view controller. There are several nav controllers connected to different tab bar items.

One of them is a tableViewController, that is populated from JSON.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

{

```
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";
   SimpleTableCell *cell = (SimpleTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)
{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}   

     //NSMutableArray for storing loaded values
[pics addObject:imageLoad];
[names addObject:[aucdict objectForKey:@"name"]];
[idcka addObject:[aucdict objectForKey:@"auction_id"]];

  // Configure the cell...
cell.nameLabel.text = [aucdict objectForKey:@"name"];
cell.priceLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",priceString];
cell.timeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",timeString];

cell.thumbnailImageView.image = imageLoad;



return cell;}
```

After clicking on row, I perform performSegueWithIdentifier:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showAuctionDetail" sender:self];}
```

and in prepareForSegue I send some data to next ViewController

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
```

{

```
namesArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:names];
picsArray =[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:pics];
IDarray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:idcka];
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showAuctionDetail"])
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    detailViewController *dViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    dViewController.selectedAuctionTitle = [namesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    dViewController.auctionPic = [picsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    dViewController.id_aukcie = [IDarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}}
```

Now comes my problem. Sometimes (this really confuses me, because it I haven't found when does it happen) when I start the application, and tap on some row, I get totally different data passed to DetailViewController. The only thing, I can guess is that my arrays are different (they contain more or less values) than actual JSON response. But that would mean, my app would crash if I clicked on first or last item in table (index out of bounds or something like that), that never happened.

I've seen this bug happened maybe 5 times randomly. I tried to run and quit app for 20 times in a row and it happened only once.

P.S. I know that class name (detailViewController) should start with capital letter, I apologize for that :)

edited: as rdelmar suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is having the call out to the server in the cellForRowAtIndexPath: method. You should put that code in viewDidLoad, and then when the data has come back, and is finished parsing, call reloadData on your table view.

Comment: Ok mistake on my part... I'm already doing it in my viewDidLoad (sending request) in cellForRowAtIndexPath I just load json response into the arrays. I apologize for that, Im going to edit my question right now.

Comment: @Yanchi, I can't ell from the code you posted whether you have more than one row in your table (because I don't see you using indexPath at all). Do you? If you have multiple rows, then the code where you move data from the json to the dictionary then array, will be called multiple times. It would be better to do that in viewDidLoad also.

Comment: Yes rdelmar I have multiple rows... I moved section of code where I transfer data from JSON to Dictionary and then to MutableArray from cellForRowAtIndexPath to viewDidLoad as you suggested, but this bug keeps happening :(

Comment: I'll also tried to save loaded values to NSMutableArray, so later on when Im preparingForSegue I can sent relevant data do DetailViewController... so I guess that may be place for error

Comment: @Yanchi  Yes, I think so. I don't think you should be adding things to your array in the cellForRowAtIndexPath: method.

Comment: So what do you suggest? I do it in cellForRowAtIndexPath, because I can conveniently use objectForKey and I know, it will iterate as many times as there are rows, right? What could possibly go wrong there? I mean, if there is some problem, that JSON wouldn't contain all records, my NSMutableArray would still had as many items as there are rows, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Yanchi, You should do all parsing and creating of your array in the viewDidLoad. Then in cellForRowAtIndexPath:, you still use objectForKey: and/or objectAtIndex: depending on your data structure, on that array. So what you have posted, is ok except for the addObject: calls -- they should be moved to viewDidLoad. That's as much as I can suggest without seeing more code -- it would be useful to see what you're doing in viewDidLoad. Also, are you updating your data on some regular basis, or do you just get the data once when the app starts up?

Comment: Rdelmar for now, I just get data once, but I'm working on refresh method. In my viewDidLoad I'm creating request (http with header authentification and parameters in body) and synchronously sending it to server. I'm glad you are so patient with me, I thank you for that :) I can post more details tomorrow (I just got back from work where my mac is).

Comment: Sorry for late respong, I've been unable to reach my macbook :) In my viewDidLoad I do following: 1. Create NSURL request 2 do some security stuff, like converting specific string into sha256 hash and creating http header verification strin 3.sending http request 4.Saving respond into NSDictionary and then moving down JSON response and saving it into NSMutableArray                         result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:returnData options:kNilOptions error:&error];result2 = [result objectForKey:@"data"]; //NSDict
jsonResults = [result objectForKey:@"data"]; //NSMutableArr

Comment: So, are you still seeing the same sporadic problem? Do you still have those addObject: calls in cellForRowAtIndexPath"? You should log indexPath in your prepareForSegue method to see if it shows the correct row selected.

Comment: Hey Rdelmar.. I moved addObjects into viewWillAppear, (also moved API request there, so my tableview refreshes). So far I'm not seeing this bug, but my tableView is almost empty (only one record), because I don't have access to server database to insert more items:) Anyway, I'm glad u took time with my problem, so Im accepting your answer.. Thanks :)